# Only one record is stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, asterisk, cdr

I configured asterisk on CentOS with storing CDR information in MySQL database but it stores only one record that I added first.

Comment: To be able to help you, you are going to have to post your relevant config files.  Otherwise, we're just guessing at ghosts about what could be wrong.

What how-to did you follow when setting up CDR->MySQL?

Comment: It's okay thanks i've fixed it today

Answer (score 0):

You need do ForkCDR if you want more then one record.